# Add a KeyCode into AOSP

Tags: android

I need to add keycode `KEYCODE_ROTARY_KNOB` with an additional parameter like direction into `AOSP`. the key event will be triggered by a tool.

I have defined the code wherever android mandates.

In my test application I have implemented `onKeyDown` and here I receive my keycode but direction information is missing.

KeyCode.java obtain method does have to correct value of direction. I have added a getter method for getting direction.

This `getDirection` is called from application `"event.getDirection"`. The method is called but the value printed for direction is still 0 (unchanged).

I doubt some other module overwrites `mDirection` defined in `KeyEvent.java`.

Answer (score 2):

In KeyEvent.java it is written:

NOTE: If you add a new keycode here you must also add it to:

- isSystem()
- isWakeKey()
- frameworks/native/include/android/keycodes.h
- frameworks/native/include/input/InputEventLabels.h
- frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml

Also Android currently does not reserve code ranges for vendor-specific key codes.  If you have new key codes to have, you MUST contribute a patch to the open source project to define those new codes.
This is intended to maintain a consistent set of key code definitions across all Android devices.

Comment: I sure did this. I have implemented it successfully with the help of another document i found online. Your answer certainly helped. thank u. I will share the document here in a while.

Comment: @SajidKhan can you please share the doc here?

Comment: Sorry i saw the comment now and I couldn't find the document. But i will share it once i find.

Comment: The solution for my question was that I missed to add steps and direction into "InputTransport.cpp" in framework/native/ .. . Input dispatcher passes the keyevent object to and request a sanitized copy for keyevent object from InputTransport. As declaration of "steps" and "direction" was missed here.  I can provide detail answer if someone is need.

Answer (score 0):

use [MIDI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary) for rotary knobs; aka. Potentiometer.

this is the most common way; if wanting to control software, those with endless rotation are the best, because they one does not have to screw them, until they bypass the current value in the controlled software, but they use relative values (despite there won't be any physically noticeable minimal or maximum position). the idea with that `KEYCODE_ROTARY_KNOB` has one huge problem: there can only be a single one knob - so how about, when you need a second one?